# I want to return 2 button in conditional react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react native 0.59.9 and i want to return 2 button in 1 conditional. but it didn't work. if just one button, it works fine but if i put 2 button i got some error

i tried put () in conditional but it didnt work

```
{this.props.options.config.editable ?
    <Button
        onPress={ () => this.bottomSheet.open()
        }
        color={buttonTextColor}
        title={locals.config.title}
    />
   //this button make the error
    <Button 
        onPress={() => this.bottomSheet.open()
        }
        color={buttonTextColor}
        title={locals.config.title}
    />
    :
    <View/>
}
```

i want the conditional return that 2 button

Comment: wrap both the button jsx inside brackets since this is multi line jsx

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap both button in the same container or React.fragment.

```
{ this.props.options.config.editable ?
    <React.Fragment>
        <Button
            onPress={
                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? this._onPressImage
                    : () => this.bottomSheet.open()
            }
            color={buttonTextColor}
            title={locals.config.title}
        />
        //this button make the error
        <Button 
            onPress={
                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? this._onPressImage
                    : () => this.bottomSheet.open()
            }
            color={buttonTextColor}
            title={locals.config.title}
        />
    </React.Fragment>
:
<View/>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In React, you need to have a single parent element that is rendered. Try wrapping your buttons with `React.Fragment`. Like this:

```
<>
    <Button
        onPress={ () => this.bottomSheet.open()
        }
        color={buttonTextColor}
        title={locals.config.title}
    />
   //this button make the error
    <Button 
        onPress={() => this.bottomSheet.open()
        }
        color={buttonTextColor}
        title={locals.config.title}
    />
</>
```